# Second Order Bandpass Filter vs Second Order High Pass and Low Pass in Series

Tags: low-pass, high-pass-filter, band-pass

Is using a second order bandpass filter less effective than using a second order high pass filter and a second order low pass filter one after the other?

I tried a bandpass filter to filter out frequencies between 0.5Hz and 15Hz, and found that there was still quite a bit of noise.

Then I used a second order high pass filter and a second order low pass filter one after the other and found that that eliminated more noise than a bandpass filter.

Why would a bandpass be worse than a high pass and low pass one after the other?

Comment: Were these filters Butterworth, Bessel, Chebyshev, Elliptic?  (If you don't know, they were likely Butterworth since those have the simplest characteristic to understand)

Comment: I believe they were Butterworth (I was taught that they have Sallen-Key configuration - same thing?) They look like the ones at this link: http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/second-order-filters.html

Comment: Yeah, that's a Butterworth response curve on the site, alright!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A second order bandpass filter has a first order roll off rate on each side of the pass band. A second order low pass filter in series with a second order high pass filter has second order roll off rates on both sides of the pass band. The two are not equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

> Then I used a second order high pass filter and a second order low
>   pass filter one after the other and found that that eliminated more
>   noise than a bandpass filter.

That now becomes equivalent to a 4th order bandpass filter and hence will generally be better than a 2nd order bandpass filter.